# javascript appendChild not working

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

Here is the code I have, I am trying to append the elements in the array to a drop down select box. The code works fine until the appendChild method. I can't figure out why that one line is not working. Here is the code

```
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Eat Page</h1>
    <p id="test">Hi</p>
    <select id="CusineList"></select>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var cuisines = ["Chinese","Indian"];
        var sel = document.getElementById('CuisineList');

        for(var i = 0; i <cuisines.length; i++){

            var optionElement = document.createElement("option");

            optionElement.innerHTML = cuisines[i];

            optionElement.value = i;//cuisines[i];
            //document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = cuisines.length;
            sel.appendChild(optionElement);

        }
    </script>

    <p> When </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? How do you know it's not working? What does "not working" mean?

Comment: I believe there's a different way of going about appending elements when it comes to select elements...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have spell miss.

Your id is `CusineList`, but when you use `CuisineList` to select.

Beside that, [your code works](http://jsfiddle.net/UpXSV/1/).

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo on

```
var sel = document.getElementById('CuisineList');
```

This should be

```
var sel = document.getElementById('CusineList');
```

Or change your html. From

```
<select id="CusineList"></select>
```

To

```
<select id="CuisineList"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

When we append node using java script, after setting nodes' attributes/properties first we have to append this node into its related parent and after appending node, we can set its content or related inner HTML / text.

here is the solution for above issue:

```
var cuisines = ["Chinese", "Indian"];var sel = document.getElementById('CusineList');
var optionElement;
for (var i = 0; i < cuisines.length; i++) {
    optionElement = document.createElement("option");
    optionElement.value = i;
    sel.appendChild(optionElement);
    optionElement.innerHTML = cuisines[i];
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = cuisines.length;
}
```

I have created a bin with the solution on http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpcn